# Perl Regex: Match this group, but not having this pattern

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need to extract some text that starts and ends with a double quote `"` but will not extract if it detects multiple double quotes.

[This is my example](https://regexr.com/3kn4v)

I tried using different look-arounds, positive/negative look-aheads and look-behinds, but it leads to an error.

In my example above, I would like to exclude the data

```
"XxXXXXX - ""                                """"XX""""""",
```

and

```
"XxXXXXX - ""XXXXX XXXXXXXX 1.4.90          """"X2""""""",
```

from being matched.

I saw some other answers here but I'm getting an error whenever I use a negative look-behind, no problems in positive look-ahead and negative look-ahead but it doesn't work.

> Edit:
>   I've added some examples regex in the link provided, and also more example data. 
>   However, I still don't want to match data above by the current regex.

Comment: I think we need some more examples of positive/negative matches. But I think the answer will be 'use two regexes'. Alternatively - given your source data is `CSV` - use a CSV parser instead.

Comment: Yes, it will be much more easier in CSV parser. But we have more different data to be processed. And also, we need to replace some of the characters, that's why I prefer to use regex rather than the CSV parser. Thanks for the advise anyway. I'll add more examples in the regexr link.

Comment: @DanD: *"but it doesn't work"* That's not the best description of misbehaving software I've read.

Comment: @DanD: If you're dealing with well-formed CSV data then you should say so. *"multiple double quotes"* isn't how CSV data is constructed. If you want help then you shouldn't restrict the available tools unnecessarily. I think [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) is still the best way to go, but you need to expand substantially on *"we need to replace some of the characters"*. I can't imagine any way that removing CSV markup would prevent you from doing this, whatever you may mean by it.

Comment: @DanD: I don't think you're telling us the truth here. If your company's  restricting you to just *two* pragmas and no core modules at all then, first of all they have no good reason, and secondly they are depriving their programmers of useful tools. If I were to believe you then they're doing it solely because they like to punish those coders who have no idea how to install a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using this:

```
"([^"]+?)"(,|$)
```

You can see it [here](https://regexr.com/3kn8b)
and also [here](https://regex101.com/r/pXYo4v/2/)

> Thanks for this one. Strange, I think I've tried this one before. But didn't get the result I've expected. Maybe it's because I didn't wait for it to be matched again.

Comment: Well this does not handle embedded quotes either, like \".
But if it is not expected do not overcomplicate it.
Also as other said many times it can be easier to go whit more regexps and probably replaces also.

Comment: Many times there is just not enough time to think and experiment hours on these small details, to solve in one step, or find the nicest solution, so better to have it fast but still robust. If you have the time and perfectionism, you can go back later, so can be useful to put a TODO comment in these cases.

Comment: You don't understand how double-quotes work within regex patterns. `/"/` is *identical* to `/\"/`. You must describe how your regex is supposed to work within Perl. *"What about using this"* doesn't help at all: ***how*** is it supposed to work without any binding operator?